# Want to trigger some event on swatch click in catalog page

Tags: magento2

I want to trigger some event on the swatch click but not on page load in the category page.

Comment: Do you mean to trigger a JS event?

Comment: thanks for replay. Yes but don't want on page load

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular JS event listeners to bind to the swatch element.

One of the least intrusive ways you can do this by doing something like this in your custom theme:

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/swatch-click'
    ]
};
```

**app/design/frontend/Your/theme/web/js/swatch-click.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
], function ($) {
    $('[class*="swatch-opt"]').on('click', '.swatch-option', function() {
        // This should trigger when swatches are clicked, NOT on page load.
        console.log('Swatch clicked...')
    });
});
```

Keep in mind this **requirejs-config.js** will load your script in all pages, even if they don't have swatches, which might not be ideal so you might want to move the loading into a different block using `text/x-magento-init` script tags.